# How to add custom class to wordpress menu <a> tag

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm creating a wordpress website from scratch and I have problem with page scroll to anchor. I'm using Bootstrap Nav Walker module for it, how should I add my `.page-scroll` class to my menu item `<a>`?

Here is my header.php menu:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapse" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-main-collapse">
                    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#page-top">
                  <img id="#page-top" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/logo3.png" alt="Brand logo">
                </a>
            </div>

            <?php
              wp_nav_menu( array(
                  'menu'              => 'primary',
                  'theme_location'    => 'primary',
                  'depth'             => 2,
                  'container'         => 'div',
                  'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right navbar-main-collapse',
                  'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
                  'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
                  'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                  'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
              );
          ?>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>
```

This is my js:

```
$(function() {
    $('.page-scroll a').bind('click', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        var $anchor_scroll = $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top;
        var $anchor_scroll_calc = $anchor_scroll;
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $anchor_scroll_calc
        }, 1500);
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Here is my wordpress menu item:

[image: Here is my wordpress menu item]

Comment: It's seems that you already added `.page-scroll` to your nav and `.page-scroll a` cover this menu links, so what's wrong?

Comment: Scroll doesn't work, it's hopping without scroll.

Comment: Any errors in the `console`?

Comment: Oh, I didn't check it. lol. http://imgur.com/MRt5LmV

Comment: In the most of the time errors in the `console` cause such problems. Fix these problems and update.

Comment: Oh, I fixed that, problem was in my wordpress URL, I needed only #service.

Comment: So are we good? :)

Answer (score 0):

Go to wp_bootstrap_navwalker

$item_output .= '';

Comment: please provide brief description while posting your answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Use**

```
function add_nav_class($output) {
    $output= preg_replace('/<a/', '<a class="scroll-link"', $output, 1);
    return $output;
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu', 'add_nav_class');
```

**and it works**